# Prompt a csv file to download as pop up using node.js and node-csv-parser (node module)

Tags: node.js, csv, export, export-to-csv

Recently I have started working with node.js. While going through a requirement in one of my projects I am facing an issue where I should be able to write some data to a csv file dynamically and let it prompt as a popup to download for user (with save and cancel options - as we normally see). After googling for some time I decided to use csv npm module https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parser. I am able to write data into a file and save it using this module. I want to prompt a popup for saving this file with/without saving the file.

my code looks something like this:

```
    // Sample Data 
    var data = [["id", "subject1", "subject2", "subject3"], ["jack", 85, 90, 68], ["sam", 77, 89, 69]]

    // Server Side Code    
    var csv = require('../../node_modules/csv');            
    var fs = require('fs');

    createCSV = function(data, callback) {
        csv().from(data).to(fs.createWriteStream('D:/test.csv')) // writing to a file           
    }

    // Client side call sample
    $("#exportToCSV").click(function() {
        callToServer.createCSV(data);
       return false;
    });
```

This is working good as far as writing the csv file is concerned.

- I want to prompt this file immediately to download for users.
- If this can be done without saving the file, that will be great.
- How can I set content-type and content-disposition as we do in PHP

Any help is greatly appreciated.
-Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did it something like this :

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=testing.csv');
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
    });

    csv().from(data).to(response)

})
.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Just a note, once you complete the above server code, link your client side location.href to the node request url [no need for ajax call].

Comment: A quick note on syntax for Express 4: 
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=testing.csv');
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
res.status(200).send(csv);

Comment: without csv library, and without express, instead of the csv() line, you can do response.write(myCSVText); resonse.end();

Answer (score 36):

Manish Kumar's answer is spot on - just wanted to include a **Express 4** syntax variant to accomplish this:

```
function(req, res) {
  var csv = GET_CSV_DATA // Not including for example.

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=testing.csv');
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  res.status(200).send(csv);

}
```

Comment: I feel like it is confusing and inconsistent to mix `setHeader` with `set`. Even though they do the same thing, they come from different places. Using `setHeader()` comes from NodeJS's `http` module. If you use `res.set`, that is from the Express framework; it allows for setting multiple headers if you give it an object: `res.set({ 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=testing.csv', 'Content-Type': 'text/csv' })`

Answer (score 12):

**Following solution is for Express**

Express is evolved, instead of setting attachment and content type header, directly use attachment api http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.attachment

Note: attachment() don't transfer the file, it just sets filename in header.

```
response.attachment('testing.csv');
csv().from(data).to(response);
```

Answer (score 3):

Express-csv is a great module for writing csv contents to stream from a node.js server, which will be sent as a response to the client (and downloaded as a file). Very easy to use.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.csv([
    ["a", "b", "c"]
  , ["d", "e", "f"]
  ]);
});
```

The docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-csv

When you pass an object, you need to prepend the headers explicitly (if you want them). Here's my my example using [npm mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

```
router.route('/api/report')
    .get(function(req, res) {
            query = connection.query('select * from table where table_id=1;', function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                var headers = {};
                for (key in rows[0]) {
                    headers[key] = key;
                }
                rows.unshift(headers);
                res.csv(rows);
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: [Nodejs send file in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046039/nodejs-send-file-in-response)

Basically, you don't have to save the file to the hard drive. Instead, try sending it directly to the `response`. If you're using something like Express then it would look something like this:

```
var csv = require('csv');
req.get('/getCsv', function (req, res) {
    csv().from(req.body).to(res);
});
```

Comment: I am not using express, but just a custom framework of node.js

Comment: Either way, the `http` module responds to requests with callbacks of the same parameters, `function (request, response)`. I think you should be able to send the results of the CSV directly to the `response`.