# node webkit: export data to csv and prompt the user to save the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I could implement the export data to csv on node webkit with node fs modules. But now I want to prompt the user to save the file in his/her desired location. Like the download pop-up in case of html. I tried doing on the lines of this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070194/prompt-a-csv-file-to-download-as-pop-up-using-node-js-and-node-csv-parser-node) and even this [file dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558126/ask-user-where-to-save-file-with-node-js). Could someone help me find a way out of this. Here's my code.

```
fs.writeFile("export.csv", data, function(err) {
    if(err) {
       console.log(err);
    } else {
        $('#export_file').show();
        $('#export_file input').on('change', function (event) {
            console.log($(this).val());
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="export_file" style="display:none">
    <input type="file" nwsaveas nwworkingdir="/data/input/" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution here http://9ijy.net/blog/view/6

Step 1 In your html file, add a Input tag block like below:

```
<input id="export_file" type="file" nwsaveas style="display:none" nwworkingdir=""/>
```

Step 2 Add a new function in your javascript file like below:

```
function saveFile(name,data) {
    var chooser = document.querySelector(name);
    chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
      console.log(this.value); // get your file name
     var fs = require('fs');// save it now
fs.writeFile(this.value, data, function(err) {
    if(err) {
       alert("error"+err);
    }
});
    }, false);

    chooser.click();  
  }
```

Step 3 Save your file where ever you like by using saveFile(name,data) function like below:

```
...

_exportCSV="you data to save";

saveFile('#export_file',_exportCSV);
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are writing the file dialog code as a callback to fs.writeFile. A
  callback means it will be called AFTER the file is saved. This is
  what might be happening right now. 1) File is written in the current
  directory where node-webkit app is running from. 2) When the file is
  saved without any errors, the dialog shows up. But this dialog is of
  no help.
- Instead, show the dialog earlier and get the file-path from it(https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/File-dialogs). Pass this path as the first arg in fs.writeFile(). Done.