# AngularJS - Receive and download CSV

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, csv

I am using a nodeJS program as a server and an AngularJS web application as the client.

To create the CSV I'm using the "express-csv" library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-csv)

Here is my server side code:

Defines:

```
var app = express();
var csv = require('express-csv');
```

Get code:

```
app.get('/exportDB', function(req, res){
    res.csv([
    ["a", "b", "c"]
  , ["d", "e", "f"]
  ]);
```

Here is my client side code:

```
$http.get("http://"+$localStorage.ip+":"+$localStorage.port+"/exportDB").success(function(response){
            // HERE I NEED A WAY TO DOWNLOAD THE RECEIVED CSV
        });
```

Needless to say it reaches the server and everything else is working just fine, but I couldnt find a way to download the CSV. Help please.

**P.S**

**Please don't say it's a duplicate of [Prompt a csv file to download as pop up using node.js and node-csv-parser (node module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070194/prompt-a-csv-file-to-download-as-pop-up-using-node-js-and-node-csv-parser-node) since the client side isn't really mentioned there.
Also, other questions are focused on server side instead of client.
There is no other question referring to AngularJS client.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just navigate:

```
location.href = "http://"+$localStorage.ip+":"+$localStorage.port+"/exportDB";
```

Comment: It works but I'm getting a file named "exportDB" without ending. (If I add the '.csv' its ok). You know how can I name the file in the server before sending?

Comment: @GuyBen-Moshe you should set headers `res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);`

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue that the solutions mentioned above with  works well with Chrome and Firefox, but not with safari/IE.

Tried out following hack and it worked for me-

`var url="http://'+$localStorage.ip+':"+$localStorage.port+'/exportDB';
    var form = angular.element("<form action='" + url +"'></form>");
    form.submit();`

File download will be handled by browser itself.
 though following is limitation to it -

1. You won't be able to handle the errors (if any) from your http get call :(   For this tried using try-catch block of javascript, but didn't work well...
2. ..you wont be able to unit test this piece of code :( :(

There is another approach that worked and it was -

`var url="http://'+$localStorage.ip+':"+$localStorage.port+'/exportDB';
$window.location.href = url;`

Suggestions and Discussions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tag and click on it:

```
    $http.get("http://"+$localStorage.ip+":"+$localStorage.port+"/exportDB").success(function(response) {
        var dataURI = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa(response);
        $('<a></a>').attr({
            download:  'db.csv',
            href: dataURI
        })[0].click();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ways of downloading csv. First approach is to create a tag and click it

Add the mimeType in below code data:application/octet-stream

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.href = 'data:'+mimeType+';charset=utf-8;base64,' + response;
 a.target = '_blank';
 a.download = "name the file here";
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.click();
```

But this solution doesn't work on IE>9 and safari>6

because safari doesn't follow download attribute for anchor tag

so for safari you can use [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

and IE this solution will work

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                // base64 string
                var base64str = response;

                // decode base64 string, remove space for IE compatibility
                var newstr =base64str.replace(/\s/g, '');
                var binary = atob(newstr);

                // get binary length
                var len = binary.length;

                // create ArrayBuffer with binary length
                var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);

                // create 8-bit Array
                var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);

                // save unicode of binary data into 8-bit Array
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                 view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
                }

                // create the blob object with content-type "application/csv"               
                var blob = new Blob( [view], { type: mimeType });
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "Name your file here");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I tried to make it simple. Assign all the back end records that you want to display in the file in the variable called obj. I will just say it as var obj = []. And inside the function just add the below code.

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
var csvContent = "Name, Address\n";

for(var i =0; i <obj.lenght; i++ ) {
  var dataString = obj[i].name + ", " + obj[i].address + "\n";
  csvContent +=  dataString;  
}
a.href = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csvContent);
a.target = '_blank';
a.download = 'myFile.csv';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```