# Unable to open blob url in IE with print dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, pdf, internet-explorer

I'm trying to open a PDF file with print dialog in IE Edge, it works fine in chrome but not in IE

MVC code to return file using Evo Pdf tool:

```
var restClient = new RestClient(Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority);
var restResponse = restClient.Execute(request);
if (restResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
     htmlModel.HtmlString = restResponse.Content;
     byte[] pdfBytes = PdfUtil.GetEvoPdfBytes(htmlModel);
     if (pdfBytes != null)
        {
             return File(pdfBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, htmlModel.PdfName + ".pdf");
        }
 }
```

Javascript code to open file with print dialog, below code works in chrome but not IE:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", "/api/HtmlToPdf", true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        req.responseType = "blob";

        req.onload = function (event) {
            var blob = req.response;
            console.log(blob.size);
            var lin = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            // Works in chrome
            var mywindow = window.open(lin, "_blank");
            mywindow.focus();
            mywindow.print();
        };
        req.send(JSON.stringify(
            {
                htmlModel: {
                    ElementSelector: "#div",
                    PageOrientation: "Portrait",
                    PdfName: "abc"
                }
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

IE11 does not support **URL.createObjectURL()**. So your code will not work for IE browser and you will not be able to open the blob with print dialog..

As a work around, you need to use  **msSaveBlob** or **msSaveOrOpenBlob** for Internet Explorer browser.

These methods allow a user to save the file on the client as if the file had been downloaded from the Internet.

```
var blobObject = new Blob(["This is sample text..."]);

window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob (blobObject, 'msSaveOrOpenBlob_testFile.txt');
```

References:

(1) [Download a blob from HTTP URL in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978795/download-a-blob-from-http-url-in-ie-11/48618032)

(2) [Saving files locally using Blob and msSaveBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh779016(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

(3) [Blob download is not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310688/blob-download-is-not-working-in-ie?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @DeepakDeepak-MSFT Ok, but do i open it with print dialog?

Comment: You will not be able to open that file using print dialog. You need to download the file.