# How can i resolve the error "access is denied" in IE browsers when downloading a PDF from my angular7 application?

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer, angular7

In my angular 7 application I have an API, when called, will download a PDF.

Here is my methods for getting the PDF:

```
getPdf() {
  const payload = { applicantId: this.idHeader, codes: 
  this.codeHeader + ':0', genderType: this.gender, data: this.data }

  this.service.getPdfConfirmationView(payload).subscribe((pdfResponse: 
  any) => {
    let dataType = 'application/pdf';
    let binaryData = [];
    binaryData.push(pdfResponse);
    let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: dataType }));
    if (pdfResponse)
      downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'ConfirmationReport');
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    })
  }
```

Here is my service for connecting to the API

```
  getPdfConfirmationView(payload) {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + 
    '/v1/report/getPdfConfirmationView',
    { headers: this.getSearchApiHeaders(payload), responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```

This works fine in Chrome browsers, I'm able to click on the link and download a PDF file to my computer.  However, in Internet Explorer 11, I am getting this error message:

```
ERROR Error: Access is denied.
  "ERROR"
    [object Error]{description: "Access is d...", message: "Access is d...", name: "Error", number: -2147024891, stack: "Error: Acce..."}
    [functions]
    __proto__[object Error] {...}
    description"Access is denied. ...
    message"Access is denied. ...
    name"Error"
    number-2147024891
    stack"Error: Access is denied. ...
```

What can I do to resolve this in IE browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't support `URL.createObjectURL()` which you use in your methods for getting PDFs. IE has its own API for creating and downloading files, which is called `msSaveBlob` or `msSaveOrOpenBlob`.

The difference between the `msSaveBlob` and `msSaveOrOpenBlob` methods is that the former only provides a **Save** button to the user whereas the latter provides both a **Save** and an **Open** button. You could use them like this in IE:

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobData, fileName);
```

For more information, you could refer to [this article in Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh779016(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978795/download-a-blob-from-http-url-in-ie-11/48618032).

---------------------------------------------------Edit-------------------------------------------------------

To make it cross browser, the code is like below:

```
if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    //IE11 & Edge
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobData, fileName); 
}
else{
   //Other browsers
    window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
    ...
}
```

You could also refer to this simple sample I made: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-coueov

Comment: I've tried the suggestion you've put forth, however, I am getting this **error:**

`core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob is not a function`

**I've replaced this line in my code:**

`downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: dataType }));`

**With this line:**

`downloadLink.href = window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob(binaryData, { type: dataType }));`

Comment: Please don't just replace it as the `msSaveOrOpenBlob` is not supported in other browsers except IE 11 and Edge. If you use it in other browsers, it can show the error "not a function". You should check the condition if IE or other browsers. I've updated my answer.