# How to return generated file download with Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, ms-word, django-rest-framework, download

I need to return generated file download as a Django REST Framework response. I tried the following:

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    template = webodt.ODFTemplate('test.odt')
    queryset = Pupils.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
    serializer = StudentSerializer(queryset)
    context = dict(serializer.data)
    document = template.render(Context(context))
    doc = converter().convert(document, format='doc')
    res = HttpResponse(
        FileWrapper(doc),
        content_type='application/msword'
    )
    res['Content-Disposition'] = u'attachment; filename="%s_%s.zip"' % (context[u'surname'], context[u'name'])
    return res
```

But it returns a msword document as `json`.

How do I make it start downloading as file instead?

Comment: You mean to say that you have created an word file which you need to pass to Front End so that Front end user should able to download it?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare exactly

Comment: Maybe after the file is generated, if it's publicly accessible from your web server (without Django code, authorisation, etc) you could send a 302 Redirect response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem by saving file in media folder and sending of the link of it to front-end.

```
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAdminUser,))
class StudentDocxViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = webodt.ODFTemplate('test.odt')
        queryset = Pupils.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = StudentSerializer(queryset)
        context = dict(serializer.data)
        document = template.render(Context(context))
        doc = converter().convert(document, format='doc')
        p = u'docs/cards/%s/%s_%s.doc' % (datetime.now().date(), context[u'surname'], context[u'name'])
        path = default_storage.save(p, doc)
        return response.Response(u'/media/' + path)
```

And handled this like in my front-end (AngularJS SPA)

```
$http(req).success(function (url) {
    console.log(url);
    window.location = url;
})
```

Comment: But how did you made media path accessible to frontend?
Like I did the same thing with path in static folder and it worked but when I did it for media folder, it said "page not found"!

Answer (score 25):

Here's an example of returning a file download directly from DRF. The trick is to use a custom renderer so you can return a Response directly from the view:

```
from django.http import FileResponse
from rest_framework import viewsets, renderers
from rest_framework.decorators import action

class PassthroughRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    """
        Return data as-is. View should supply a Response.
    """
    media_type = ''
    format = ''
    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data

class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Example.objects.all()

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=True, renderer_classes=(PassthroughRenderer,))
    def download(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()

        # get an open file handle (I'm just using a file attached to the model for this example):
        file_handle = instance.file.open()

        # send file
        response = FileResponse(file_handle, content_type='whatever')
        response['Content-Length'] = instance.file.size
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % instance.file.name

        return response
```

Note I'm using a custom endpoint `download` instead of the default endpoint `retrieve`, because that makes it easy to override the renderer just for this endpoint instead of for the whole viewset -- and it tends to make sense for list and detail to return regular JSON anyway. If you wanted to selectively return a file download you could add more logic to the custom renderer.

Comment: AssertionError:  .accepted_media_type not set on Response
getting this error sometimes.

Answer (score 13):

This may work for you:

```
file_path = file_url
FilePointer = open(file_path,"r")
response = HttpResponse(FilePointer,content_type='application/msword')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=NameOfFile'

return response.
```

For FrontEnd code refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792681/angularjs-receive-and-download-csv/36793906#36793906)

Comment: I don't get this line `yourFilePointer.write(response,text)
`. My file is already generated and saved on server. What `text` should I write there?

Comment: Text will be the your word file text.

Comment: as we write text file like `f = open('c:\file.doc', "w")
f.write(text)`

Comment: As I said, my file is already on disk. I don't need to write it

Comment: It should be: ´response = HttpResponse(FilePointer.read(), content_type='application/msword')´

Comment: How would you protect that with csrf? Acording to django document you need to use render() for it to work

Answer (score 10):

I am using DRF and i found a view code to download file, which would be like

```
from rest_framework import generics
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

class FileDownloadListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):

    def get(self, request, id, format=None):
        queryset = Example.objects.get(id=id)
        file_handle = queryset.file.path
        document = open(file_handle, 'rb')
        response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(document), content_type='application/msword')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % queryset.file.name
        return response
```

and url.py will be

```
path('download/<int:id>/',FileDownloadListAPIView.as_view())
```

I am using React.js in frontend and i get a response like

```
handleDownload(id, filename) {
  fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/example/download/${id}/`).then(
    response => {
      response.blob().then(blob => {
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let a = document.createElement("a");
      console.log(url);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = filename;
      a.click();
    });
  });
}
```

and after i got successful in downloading a file which also opens correctly and i hope this gonna work. Thanks

Comment: what if you dont know the content_type? how to handle auto content_type

Answer (score 6):

For me, using Python 3.6, Django 3.0, and DRF 3.10, The problem came from using the wrong type of response. I needed to use a `django.http.HttpResponse`, as seen below:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
...
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.csv'
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

In models.py

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=attachment_directory_path, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self.file.name.split('/')[-1:][0]
```

in views.py

```
import mimetypes
from django.http import FileResponse


class AttachmentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=True)
    def download(self, request, **kwargs):
        att = self.get_object()
        file_handle = att.file.open()

        mimetype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(att.file.path)
        response = FileResponse(file_handle, content_type=mimetype)
        response['Content-Length'] = att.file.size
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename={}".format(att.filename)
        return response
```

and in frontend, I used axios for download files. `api` is axios client.

```js
export function fileDownload(url, filename){
  return api.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
    .then((response)=>{
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute('download', filename);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    })
}
```

hope that it helps

Answer (score 0):

Using [django-downloadview](https://django-downloadview.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views/object.html) this can be done like so:

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from django_downloadview import ObjectDownloadView


class DocumentViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    @action(detail=True)
    def download(self, request, pk):
        return ObjectDownloadView.as_view(
            model=, # your model here
        )(request, pk=pk)
```

The viewset can then be registered via DRF routers.

Answer (score 0):

```
class FileDownloadListView(generics.ListAPIView):

    def get(self, request, id):
        media = Media.objects.get(id=id)
        filepath = media.video.path
        mimetype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)
        filename = os.path.basename(media.video.name)
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
            response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(file), content_type=mimetype)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}'
            return response


    path('media/download/<int:id>/', FileDownloadListView.as_view()),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).