# Read from file in nodejs and display it

Tags: node.js, heroku, github

When I run my nodejs code locally it works fine. I get the desired output.
My Code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("index.html", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

When run locally

[image]

- index.html contains "Hello World from index.html" and is in the same directory.

**Problem: 
When I try to deploy web.js(which contains the same code as above) on heroku it doesn't seems to work.**
I want "Hello World from index.html" to be displayed when I deploy it on heroku.

- web.js is in my [github repository](https://github.com/saurabh2816/bitstarter)

Following commands are executed 
[image]

After `git push heroku master`

[image]

Here is what heroku URL shows[image]

Background: I'm using AWS Ubuntu 12.04 and my github repository is [this](https://github.com/saurabh2816/bitstarter) which contains the required web.js file. I'm using Cygwin.

What could possibly be wrong.I'm new to nodejs so I think I'm missing something very basic here. If you're an expert please be kind enough to answer this stupid question. I've literally spent my night trying to figure it out. 
**All I want is to read from index.html file and display text it contains on "http://nameless-headland-9348.herokuapp.com/" when deployed on Heroku.**

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to reference file `index.html` and using relative path. This might not work on heroku, and it will try to load file from somewhere else.

So what you want is to load it relatively to your app.js is:

```
fs.readFile(path.join(process.cwd(), 'index.html'), function(err, data) {
```

As well all it will do (your code) is console log your stuff. While there is no http server and anything, and you are trying to access it through browser. There is nothing server as response.

Please read this answer, in order to learn how to send files via http: [Nodejs send file in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046039/nodejs-send-file-in-response)

Comment: I'm new to nodejs so is this what you mean?

`var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");
http.createServer(function(request,response){
fs.readFile(path.join(process.cwd(), 'index.html'), function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        return console.log(err);
    console.log(data.toString());
}).listen(8080);
});`
I didn't understand how to use http server.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read and try the [Heroku getting started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs) for Node.js?  You don't provide any logs, so it's difficult to diagnose your problem, but your last code snippet has a clear problem - it listens on port 8080.  You should listen on the PORT number Heroku provides to you (see the doc again), using something like this to retrieve it `process.env.PORT`

Comment: What was the problem in the end?

Comment: the issue was that my port was set to 8080 instead of `process.env.PORT`