# Nodejs server to serve wav file to Java client

Tags: java, node.js, client-server

I am trying to send the sound (.wav) file form node server to the java client.
Since, I am new on both, I cant be able to figure out how to achieve this?
I have written following nodejs program.

```
var fileStream = files.createReadStream ("/tmp/tts_out.wav");
fileStream.on('open', function(){
fileStream.pipe(socket);
```

I am unable to write the program. Is there anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Set the content type when you send or stream a file as a response , so that the client to act accordingly . For example browsers need needs to know the file content to play the file .

There is already a similar question please refer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046039/nodejs-send-file-in-response)