# How correctly use fastGet method of ssh2-sftp-client library in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am tring to load file from remote SFTP server in Node.js application. I use [ssh2-sftp-client](https://github.com/jyu213/ssh2-sftp-client) library for this task. Unfortunatly I have error. What I did wrong?

When I use such code it return me list of all files in the path of remote SFTP server correctly.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  sftp.connect(config.sftpServer).then(() => {
    return sftp.list('/reports')
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
})
```

In console I see such result:

```
[ { type: '-',
    name: '1548244803285.csv',
    size: 74589,
    modifyTime: 1548278757000,
    accessTime: 1548513471000,
    rights: { user: 'rwx', group: 'rwx', other: 'rwx' },
    owner: 1030,
    group: 1022 } ]
```

If I try to download the specific file with `fastGet` method, Node.js raise error.

```
return sftp.fastGet('/reports/1548244803285.csv', path.join(process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE, 'downloads/'))
```

**ERROR:**

```
Error: Failed to get /reports/NNogerbek1548244803285.csv: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'C:\Users\NNogerbek\downloads'
    at C:\Users\NNogerbek\WebstormProject\web-app\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\src\index.js:192:16
    at cbfinal (C:\Users\NNogerbek\WebstormProject\web-app\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\sftp.js:1038:11)
    at SFTPStream._transform (C:\Users\NNogerbek\WebstormProject\web-app\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\sftp.js:389:17)
    at SFTPStream.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:190:10)
    at SFTPStream._read (C:\Users\NNogerbek\WebstormProject\web-app\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\sftp.js:183:15)
    at SFTPStream.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:178:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:410:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:394:5)
    at SFTPStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:294:11)
    at Channel.ondata (_stream_readable.js:666:20)
```

The user which I use to connection to remore SFTP server has rights to read, write. Don't understand whats the problem.

---

Well, finally I found the reason of the problem. `EISDIR` means that application is trying to do something to a file but it is a directory.

The correct code is that:

```
return sftp.fastGet('/reports/1548244803285.csv', path.join(process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE, 'downloads/1548244803285.csv'))
```

Now I want to return file in browser as response. How to make it correctly?

Comment: Already explained on that link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046039/nodejs-send-file-in-response

Comment: I had to update my localePath to point to a file instead of a directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my final working code:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const fileName = req.body.file_name;

    const remotePath = '/put_your_path_here/' + fileName;

    const localePath = path.join(process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE, 'Downloads/' + fileName);

    sftp.connect(config.sftpServer, 'once').then(() => {
        sftp.fastGet(remotePath, localePath, {}).then(() => {
            res.header('Content-type', 'text/csv; charset=windows-1251');
            res.sendFile(localePath);
            sftp.end();
        }).catch((err) => {
            sftp.end();
            console.log(err, 'fastGet method error');
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        sftp.end();
        console.log(err, 'connect method error');
    });
});
```