# Sending pdf files to user from nodejs to reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have pdf documents stored in the file system on the server side.

I need to let the user download one of them when he/she clicks on download.

The problem is that I know how to send a file from NodeJS to browser but here the request will be made by a ReactJS axios request. So when I send a file, the response will go to react. How do I send that pdf file to the user? Do I access the file system directly using my front end code?

I get the following in the browser console when I log the response after I do `res.sendFile(file_path)` in NodeJS

[image]

How do I process this so that I can make the user download the pdf?

Comment: are you using some reverse proxy like Nginx, as it is highly optimized for sharing static files?

Comment: No, I am not using Nginx. Actually my issue is to somehow allow the user to download the pdf file, but since the request is to be made by react, I cannot make him download the file.

Comment: what is your end goal?

Comment: Once the user clicks on download, he/she should be able to download that particular file stored in my file system (whatever method I use) .
Is it fine if I do not involve the server end in this ( I am not sure if it the correct thing to do)?

Comment: there must be an option for sendFile in response, or you can send data back to client and generate pdf on client side

Comment: Yes, the sendfile is working, but what do I do to make the user download the file or how do I process the once I receive it.

Comment: after receiving file you can render pdf file in your browser... if file returned in byte you have to convert it into browser readable file.

Comment: That is exactly what I am asking, I can send the file using res.sendFIle, after that how do I process it?
The header says:
cache-control: "public, max-age=0"
content-type: "application/pdf"
last-modified: "Thu, 06 Jun 2019 07:10:57 GMT"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) to download the file. Below is the function I'm using for pdf download. (`response.data` is the Buffer that nodejs sends back as a response)

```
import FileSaver from 'file-saver';
...

_onPdfFetched() {
  FileSaver.saveAs(
    new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' }),
    `sample.pdf`
  );
}
```

or you can just show pdf to the user

```
window.open(response.data, '_blank');
```

**Edit**

The axios call should be like this:

```
axios.get(url, {
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  headers: {
      Accept: 'application/pdf',
  },
});
```

**Edit 2**

The nodejs code should be like this:

```
router.post('/api/downloadfile',(req, res, next) => {
  const src = fs.createReadStream('path to sample.pdf');

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=sample.pdf',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'Binary'
  });

  src.pipe(res); 
});
```

Comment: The download does take place but the pdf content is totally distorted.

Comment: I told you, response.data is the Buffer that nodejs sends back as a response. You should send Buffer from nodejs

Comment: I searched a lot, but I did not get how to send the file buffer from node. I used file.pipe() and other measures but with the same result. Is there any document I could refer to or could you tell me how exactly is the buffer sent at the server side.

Comment: can you provide the nodejs code in order to help you?

Comment: `router.post('/api/downloadfile',(req,res,next)=>{
  pathname=path.join(__dirname,'../../../documents','sample.pdf');

  res.sendFile(pathname);
})`

I have also tried this but to no avail:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046039/nodejs-send-file-in-response)

Comment: if you try to replace `res.sendFile(pathname)` with `res.attachment(pathname)` is it working? Because this one adds the correct headers

`// Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"`
`// Content-Type: application/json`

or even better you can use `res.download(pathname)` which might do the job for you

Comment: I tried both with the following axios call but the same result:

`axios.post('http://localhost:7000/api/downloadfile',{

            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/pdf',
            },})
        .then(res=>{
            console.log("RESPONSE IS:",res);
            FileSaver.saveAs(
                new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' }),
                `name.pdf`
              );
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log("error",err);
        })`

Comment: I edit my answer with the nodejs code. I hope this will help you

Comment: Tried it man, same result. Even with different pdfs, the content is totally lost. I have no clue what to do. For black and white pdfs, I  just get blank pages.

Comment: If you try to run your endpoint on postman what's the response?

Comment: With postman, I get the correct pdf. No data loss at all.
My front end call:

`axios.post('http://localhost:7000/api/downloadfile',{

            responseType: 'arraybuffer',

            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/pdf',
            },})
        .then(res=>{
            console.log("RESPONSE IS:",res);
            FileSaver.saveAs(

                new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' }),

                `name.pdf`

              );
           
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log("error",err);
        })`

Comment: maybe the response doesn't need to be converted to `Blob`. Try just to pass the response data on `File saver` like this:

`FileSaver.saveAs(response.data, 'sample.pdf');`

Comment: No, I get an error :Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL

and looks like one needs to use blob with filesaver.

Comment: ok I see what is happening. You are doing `axios.post`, not `axios.get`, which means that the options should be the third parameter (on post call the second parameter is the request body). So it should look like this:

`axios.post(url, {}, { responseType: 'arraybuffer', headers: { Accept: 'application/pdf'}})`

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks a lot. So that was it? Wrong parameter list? And could you explain what is happening here, I mean I get that we are converting the pdf into a stream of bytes and then processing it. Is that all?

Comment: Actually I believe the problem was the axios call. Now, about the nodejs code I gave you, it's for better usage of files using pipes. You can see [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93/)

Comment: This answer got me a long ways.  But for some reason the browser is not correctly opening the pdf file.  My axios call looks like this: `axios
  .get('SDS/openPDFFile', {
   params: { pdf },
   responseType: 'arraybuffer',
   headers: {
    Accept: 'application/pdf'
   }
  })
  .then((res) => {
   console.log(res);
   window.open(res.data, '_blank');
  });`  And then the browser tries to open: `http://localhost:3000/[object%20ArrayBuffer]`

Comment: @dmikester1 Did you try to convert to response to Blob?

Comment: I Use this way in Node Backend:

     ```res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

      res.setHeader(
        "Content-Disposition",
        `attachment; filename= someFileName.pdf`
      );

      res.end(data);
```

In the frontend using Axios:

```
axios.post("yourapi/blah/blah",{data: {somedata: somevalue},},{responseType:"arraybuffer",headers: {Accept: "application/pdf",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((result) => {
        FileDownload(
          new Blob([result.data], { type: "application/pdf" }),
          fileName
        );
      })
```

Comment: I think you are missing the `'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'Binary'` header in nodejs code