# Set nodejs express response size

Tags: node.js, express

I have done this before somewhere but I can't find where anymore. My problem is, my `response.send(myJSON)` is too big (the myJSON is too big) so my content get cut off before it reaches the user. How can I set the `response.send()` to a bigger size or unlimited even?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs send file in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046039/nodejs-send-file-in-response)

Comment: try increasing the timeout to a time greater than your response time.Then the user is going to receive all the response data

Answer (score -1):

you can use the npm package [express-response-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-response-size) to customize response of the server.