# Node.js does not pipe contents

Tags: node.js, httpserver

I have a simple Web server, which should send a file. I took the code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10047018/402322).

```
#! /usr/bin/node

const FS     = require ('fs');
const HTTP   = require ('http');

const server = HTTP.createServer ();

server.on ('request', (request, response) => {
  switch (request.url) {
  case '/':
    switch (request.method) {
    case 'GET':
      console.log ("GET /");
      let stat = FS.statSync ('index.html');
      console.log (stat.size);
      response.writeHead (200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                                 'Content-Lenght': stat.size });
      let index = FS.createReadStream ('index.html', 'UTF-8');
      index.pipe (response);
      response.end ();
      return;
    }
    break;
  }
  response.writeHead (400, {});
  response.end ();
});

server.listen (8080);
```

When I try to send a GET request with `curl`, I get no content. My server reports, that the `index.html` file has 324 bytes:

```
$ ./server.js 
GET /
324
```

But `curl` does not show the content. There header contains the content length, but the body is missing.

```
$ curl -v --noproxy \* http://localhost:8080/
[...]
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Lenght: 324
< Date: Sat, 21 Nov 2020 19:24:31 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I looks as if the connection got closed before the file has been piped. Is the the error and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `response.end ();`.  You're prematurely closing the response BEFORE the `.pipe()` gets to do its work (it's asynchronous so it finishes over time and returns before it's done).

In the default configuration, `.pipe()` will end your response for you when it's done.

You will also notice that [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10047018/402322) you took this idea from did not have a `response.end()`.