# Is there a way for me to supply the http server in NodeJS with an html file for hosting?

Tags: html, node.js

Current code below

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("Ping server page");
});

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.eblue("\nListening on port 8080");
  console.eblue("WEB SERVER STARTED\n");
});
```

I just want to know if their is a way to make a fully featured site and host it using node.js

Comment: Sure. But you probably want to have a look into https://expressjs.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js send file in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046039/node-js-send-file-in-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using Express (a node.js package) for web servers, which you can then serve static files - including HTML - through with `express.static`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (if I understood correctly), you just need to serve the html as a static file like this:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html